# Return multiple rows and use in another function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to return the result in one function and use the result in another function.
But the function `extract()` returns only one record. Expectation is to return all the records from a table.

```
def extract(self):
    data = self.oracle_conn().execute('select * from employees').fetchall()
    for row in data:
        return row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to return a list of all records:

```py
def extract(self):
    data = self.oracle_conn().execute('select * from employees').fetchall()
    return [row for row in data]
```